Any way to stop default shipping address being changed by a NetSuite website
As the title says, is there any way to stop default shipping/billing addresses being changed by a NetSuite website (SCA in this case). Clients really hate this feature on a B2B site. If a customer checks out (or nearly checks out), the last shipping options become the new default which screws up people a lot.
I've tried user events and workflows, but they're not triggered. My workaround is a suitelet to reset the defaults after changing the LiveOrder Model, but that's slow and really ugly.
Surely there must be a cleaner way to do this? A magic checkbox somewhere.

What I have done is add a checkbox on address records. Call it 'preferred shipping address'
Then in an after submit script on the sales order I update the customer's default shipping address based on the customer's addressbook address subrecord that has that checked.

This is a nice idea, but it doesn't work in a lot of cases. Customers can get half way through the checkout and change the default address without ever placing the order and creating the sales order.

True, The code that does the reset can also be put in a scheduled or map/reduce script and can be run on a schedule so  that any partial changes are reverted. Depending on your needs you can also change your checkout to disallow address changes.

Scheduled script would work better. It's still not air tight though. I'm hoping NetSuite might read this and add a checkbox to stop it, it would be such a simple win.

You can also just leave the native behavior in place for the website, and use the suggested "preferred shipping address" custom field in a client script to override the default shipping address selection in the UI.  Here I'm assuming that the "clients" you refer to in your question are the NetSuite account owners, not the end customers who are using the website.
